# Facing error when running npm Production

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

When i am trying to run npm as Production then i am getting the error  **throw new JS_Parse_Error(message, filename, line, col, pos);** but npm dev is working fine

Comment: what script your `npm prod` runs? is it same as `npm dev`?

Comment: yes for production

Comment: I can't help you unless i see the command/line which is throwing the error. Looks like json formatting issue from the error message

Comment: undefined:1625
    throw new JS_Parse_Error(message, filename, line, col, pos);
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (()
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (/var/www/html/pivot/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:86:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`